# Ask someone to explain something again

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, usage

Say someone has explained something to me days ago. But I forgot basically everything when we talked about it again later, I wanted to ask him to explain that for me again.
Can I use "*refresh / refreshment*", like "*can I get some refreshment on this*" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say

> Can I get some **refreshment**

the person you are speaking to might hand you a cold drink

> **Please refresh my memory**

is the often used phrase you are looking for

> **Please refresh my memory** about our conversation last week
>   **Please refresh my memory**, what did you say about...

Comment: Just to add to this, sometimes people ask for "a refresher", but this sounds a bit like a buzzword to me.

Comment: There are **refresher** courses to **remind** students of materials, **refresher** is also shorthand for a **drink**(!) No, I don't have a problem...

Comment: I think "can you" sounds more native than "please" in this situation.  As in "Hey, can you refresh my memory about our conversation last week?"

Comment: @Kevin I would say your phrasing is more **informal**, both are **native**, and it's still always nice to say **please**